# Xamarin android. The name 'assets' does not exist in the current context

Tags: android-fragments, xamarin.android, typeface

In my app I am using a fragment and inside the fragment I am trying to use

```
view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv1).Typeface = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Assets, "fonts/Montserrat_Light.ttf");
```

to change the typeface of a textview. But I am getting an error that 'The name 'assets' does not exist in the current context'
This is the fragment code

```
public class xFragment : Fragment
{
    const string ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";
    private int mPage;

    public static xFragment newInstance(int page)
    {
        var args = new Bundle();
        args.PutInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
        var fragment = new xFragment ();
        fragment.Arguments = args;
        return fragment;
    }

    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPage = Arguments.GetInt(ARG_PAGE);
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.AgeLayout, container, false);
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv1).Typeface = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Assets, "fonts/Montserrat_Light.ttf");
        if (mPage == 2)
        {
            view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.AgeERLayout, container, false);
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and was so easy. I just had to use `Activity.Assets`